# How to duplicate a const array in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a constant array items[], i want to copy it to array2[].

how to do it when i do it the item array get printed two times in console.

how to achieve this aim?

```js
window.onload="arr1()"
function arr1()
{
const items = [  
      { label: '1:40', url: '1.png'  },
      { label: '2:20', url: '2.png'  },
      { label: '3:50', url: '3.png'  },
      { label: '4:45', url: '4.png'  }]
console.log(items);
console.log(arr2);
}
```

Comment: const array2 = Object.assign([], items)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function arr1()
{
const items = [  
      { label: '1:40', url: '1.png'  },
      { label: '2:20', url: '2.png'  },
      { label: '3:50', url: '3.png'  },
      { label: '4:45', url: '4.png'  }]
console.log(items);
const arr2 =  Object.assign([],items)
console.log(arr2);
}

window.onload=arr1()
```

Im not sure if this is what you are looking for. but there is a function that is called 'onload' and then it creates an array prints it, copies it and then prints it again

Answer (score 2):

```
const items = [
        { label: '1:40', url: '1.png'  },
        { label: '2:20', url: '2.png'  },
        { label: '3:50', url: '3.png'  },
        { label: '4:45', url: '4.png'  }];
 const arr2 = items;
  console.log(items);
  console.log(arr2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
`var arr2 = items.slice();` 
As slice() creates a new array and return it.
Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

just assign items to arr2 to copy all data of items into arr2 like

```
var arr2 = items;
```